# Calcular porcentagem em campo dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho inputs tipo `text` onde uma função em javascript pega esses valores do input e faz uma conta de porcentagem, funciona corretamente, o problema é que dependendo da entrada de dados esses campos se tornam dinâmicos, gerando vários inputs com o mesmo ID, então a função do javascript não consegue referenciar e não faz o cálculo. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia resolver isso ou trocar o método para o cálculo?

PS: o sistema calculava antes os dados recebidos em php mesmo, porém o usuário precisa ver o resultado da conta em tempo real quando ele insere o valor da porcentagem.

Comment: Posta o código até onde você tem para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: Elementos na mesma página que partilham o mesmo ID é inválido, incorreto e nunca vai funcionar. A solução para o teu problema passa por deixar de trabalhar com `id` e começar a trabalhar com `class`.

Answer (score 0):

"serão 3 inputs com o mesmo ID"
Eu não sei como está o seu código, mas só para lhe mostrar que dá para recuperar tudo do outro lado do php - mesmo com elementos de mesmo id.

Eu sugiro que vc gere o id dinamicamente (eu não sei se essa é a sua dúvida) mas aqui vai um código que mostra que dá para passar as informações e recuperar com POST em php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <input id="as"  type="text" name="valor[]" value="1"><br>
        <input id="as"  type="text" name="valor[]" value="2"><br>
        <input id="as"  type="text" name="valor[]" value="3"><br>
        <input id="as"  type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

        <?php

        $arr=$_POST["valor"];
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($arr);
        echo '</pre>';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note o que acontece na array POST:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teste esse código para recuperar os valores usando classes e não Ids

```
//HTML
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input id="as" class="tosend" type="text" name="valor[]" value="1"><br>
  <input id="as" class="tosend" type="text" name="valor[]" value="2"><br>
  <input id="as" class="tosend" type="text" name="valor[]" value="3"><br>
  <input id="btntosend" class="btntosend" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
//Js
$('#btntosend').on( 'click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
   $('.tosend').each(function() {//Passar por cada radio da classe rdShipMo
      alert($(this).val());
   });   
});
```

Veja o [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkfgbkns/). Vc nem precisa do Id.

Comment: Obrigado por responder @zwitterion, esse array dinâmico já está sendo feito no código, é justamente esse o problema com o javascript, usando seu exemplo acima, suponha que esse input tenho um id e o javascript usa ele como referencia para buscar um valor, ai quando ele for dinâmico (3 inputs como no exemplo) a função do js não vai conseguir achar a referência (por ter 3 inputs com o mesmo id), entende?

Comment: Sim entendo. Estava mostrando que mesmo com o memo id essa técnica de usar array como nome o POST ou o GET consegue recuperar os valores. Então vc tem duas possibilidades: 1- criar Ids dinamicamente com javascript ou 2-mudar sua forma de enviar as informações do form para  o servidor.

Comment: Vou editar a minha resposta para lhe mostrar como vc pode fazer diferente usando JS